# C# cast type to generic interface without knowing interface type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, reflection, interface

Is it possible to cast to a generic interface type where you don't know the actual generic type but DO know that the type is derived from some shared interface?

I have a generic interface:

```
public interface IFooGenericObjectProvider<TModel> where TModel : class, IBaseModelType
{
    SomeObject ProvideSomeObject(TModel model);
}
```

Classes implement it like so:

```
public class SomeObjectProvider : IFooGenericObjectProvider<ConcreteModel>
{
    public SomeObject ProvideSomeObject(ConcreteModel model)
    {
        // create instance of 'SomeObject' using 'ConcreteModel'
    }
}
```

And I'm creating instances of types which implement the `IFooGenericObjectProvider<TModel>` type via reflection / `Activator.CreateInstance`

This all works great however the issue arises when I need to use the created types.

I'm trying to cast them to `IFooGenericObjectProvider<IBaseModelType>` when I need to call the method from the implemented interface, and since all `ConcreteModel` instances derive from a shared `IBaseModelType` interface, I figured this would be perfectly fine but it throws an exception during the cast:

> Unable to cast object of type 'SomeObjectProvider' to
> type
> 'IFooGenericObjectProvider`1[IBaseModelType]'.

I can fix this by changing to:

```
public class SomeObjectProvider : IFooGenericObjectProvider<IBaseModelType>
{}
```

However the caller is provided with an instance of `IBaseModelType` rather than `ConcreteType` which is what I would like:

```
public SomeObject ProvideSomeObject(IBaseModelType model)
{
    // This works, but would like access to the concrete model type instead
}
```

I know that I can cast `IBaseModelType model` to the concrete type but this isn't as nice and is an extra step for the caller.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? Perhaps theres another approach that would work better?

Comment: The type system is stopping you from making an error. If the original cast would work then we could do `(IFooGenericObjectProvider<IBaseModelType>)(new SomeObjectProvider()).ProvideSomeObject(new AnyPossibleTypeDerivedFromIBaseModelType())` and now the `ProvideSomeObject` method in `SomeObjectType` is receiving a instance of the wrong type.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That makes sense. So its not possible to do this directly then.

Comment: Can you show that you try to create instance of 'SomeObject'?

Comment: @vernou I can add it to the question if you think it will help? It's nothing interesting though. Or did you mean to ask for how I create the provider instances instead?

Comment: I don't understand how create 'SomeObject' using 'ConcreteModel' and the need to cast.

Comment: @vernou The `ConcreteModel` just contains properties that the caller may need that could be used to create an instance of `SomeObject`. You can cast `IBaseModelType` to `ConcreteModel` since it derives from that interface. Does that make sense?

Comment: Maybe... but like explained by @Damien_The_Unbeliever, it isn't possible to do generic covariance with a input parameter.

Comment: You need to up the generic in the class that ref the provider.

Comment: Since you use reflection to create an instance - you can as well continue with that approach and call method via reflection also.

Comment: @Evk That's a good shout. I'll give that a try

Comment: Sorry @vernou not sure what you mean by `You need to up the generic in the class that ref the provider.`?

Comment: @Evk thanks for the suggestion. I managed to get it working by invoking the `ProvideSomeObject` method against the type and passing an instance of the class as the `target`. E.g:

`providerType.InvokeMember("ProvideSomeObject", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, providerInstance, new object[] { model });`

Comment: @DGibbs, I mean the class that use `IFooGenericObjectProvider` need to be generic also. Just a idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around this by invoking the method via reflection on the type/instance.

For exampple:

```
var providerInstance =  ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(this.serviceProvider, providerType);
var someObject = providerType.InvokeMember("ProvideSomeObject", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, providerInstance, new object[] { model });
```